# Tkinter login using notepad as database

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def btnClick(self):
    filereader = open("Login.txt", 'r+')
    dataload = filereader.readlines()
    UN=self.entr1.get()
    PW=self.entr2.get()
    for line in dataload:
        (username,password) = line.split('|')
        UN2 = username
        PW2 = password
        if (UN==UN2) & (PW==PW2):
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Success", "Successfully login!")
            self.main()
        else:
            tkMessageBox.showinfo("Error", "Incorrect login credentials!")
            self.clear()
    filereader.close()
    return
```

I have the code above for the event when the user clicked login button, Im using notepad as a database and this is the data inside

> User|1234
>   Admin|1234

I think my codes are right but when I run it, it always says incorrect even I entered the correct data. Can you please help me identify my mistakes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a simple `print` statement to output the values that you read from the file, and compare them with what you actually entered.

---

Since `.readlines()` does not strip the line-breaks, the lines/passwords you read from the file always end with a `\n` character.

You should remove that; a simple way is to just call `replace('\n', '')` or `rstrip('\n')`:

```
(username,password) = line.replace('\n', '').split('|')
```

or use

```
filereader.read().splitlines()
```

instead of `filereader.readlines()`